# Execute a distributed transaction for an Oracle linked server using SQL Server 2000

Tags: sql-server, oracle10g, distributed, linked-server

I'm trying to execute a distributed transaction for a single Oracle linked server using SQL Server 2000, I came up with the following script:

```
BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION;
  SET XACT_ABORT  off;
  GO

  SELECT MAX(DEPTNO)+1,
  FROM [WSF08_CONTA_ORADATA_II]..[SCOTT].DEPT

  SET XACT_ABORT  on;
  GO

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

As soon as the script is ran I get the following errors followed by SQL Management studio freezing and closing the connection.

> Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>       The OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "WSF08_CONTA_ORADATA_II" reported an error. The provider reported an unexpected catastrophic failure.
>       Msg 7303, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>       Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "WSF08_CONTA_ORADATA_II".

What is going on?

*P.D:

1. I can create/update/delete data using regular queries but error shows up when the `DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION` clause is involved.
2. We recently upgraded or linked servers to Oracle 10g, It is worth to mention that I did not run into issues we were using 9i.

Comment: yes, I can do SELECT and Insert with out "BEGIN DISTRIBUTED TRANSACTION; " option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To enroll SQL Server and Oracle in a distributed transaction MSDTC needs to have XA transactions enabled. See [Supporting XA Transactions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753563(WS.10).aspx):

> When the DTC acts as an XA-compliant
>   transaction manager, **Oracle**, IBM DB/2,
>   Sybase, Informix, and other
>   XA-compliant resource managers can
>   participate in transactions that the
>   DTC controls.